# I an having trouble figuring out where my variables call from or to

Tags: java

can someone explain what variables do what in beginning Java? I am confused about what the variables point to in the bit of code I am doing for my computer class. I am too new to even know what to search for to get the right answer and the book I am using doesn't help explain anything as it names all the variables the same which confuses me on what is called from where.
Thank you
Chad

Where does the `public void setEmpID(int NewID)` set this.empID to NewID?

```
// access modifier is set to public and a class is declared and named Employee
public class Employee  
{   
    private int empID; 
    private String firstName; 
    private String lastName; 
    private double monthlySalary; (Are these to store the variable values from the main method until class creation or are they defining variables in the object that will be created?)

    //Constructor intializes class Employee to create object Employee with instance variables above. Must be same name as class

    **public Employee(int empID, String firstName, String lastName, double newSalary) //(is this the storage until the class is created or the defining of the variables for the object that will be created?)**
    {
        //ensures empID is a positive number before assignment
        if (empID > 0.0) 
            //assigns empID to variable "empID"
            **this.empID = empID; //where does this assign empID? in the new object or in this class temporarily until the object is created?**

        //assigns firstName to variable "firstName"
        this.firstName = firstName; 

        // assigns lastName to variable "lastName"
        this.lastName = lastName;                         

        //ensure monthlySalary is a positive number before assignmentand if 
        //ends constructor
    }

    **//method that sets the empID(where are these set?)**
    public void setEmpID(int newID)
    {
        this.empID = newID;
    }

    //method that sets the firstName
    public void setFirstName(String newFirst)
    {
        this.firstName = newFirst;
    }

     //method that sets the lastName
    public void setLastName(String newLast)
    {
        this.lastName = newLast;
    }

    //method that sets the monthlySalary for the new obj
    public void setMonthlySalary(double newSalary)

    {
        this.monthlySalary = newSalary;
    }

    **//Gets empid from the object and returns empID to the calling method (I think this is right)**
    public int getEmpID()
    {
        return empID;
    }  

    //gets first name from the object and returns first name to the calling method  
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }  

    //gets last name from the object and returns last name to the calling method  
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }  

    //gets monthly salary from the object and returns it to the calling method  
    public double getMonthlySalary()
    {
        return monthlySalary;          
    }

}
```

Comment: Just so you know the `**` are not required for your comments

Comment: ok thanks. I wanted to bold the parts I had questions about just to make it easier to see the parts so people reading the post could quickly find the code in question. For some reason when I ** the parts they weren't boldface when posted.

Comment: Oh, that was because they were indented so the question does not recognise it as bold

Comment: Also did my answer help clear things up?

Comment: I just figured out why. The brackets were seen by the forum software and it just posted verbatim everything in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know about variable visibility this might help. [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private).

As for when variables have the same name see the code below

**Example.java**

```
public class Example {
    private int empID = 0; //Creates a global variable

    public Example(int empID) { //Creates a local variable that is 
                                //initiated when contructor is called
        this.empID = empID; //Calls the global variable and sets it
                            //equal to the local variable
        exampleMethod(); //Calls the method below
    }

    private void exampleMethod() {
        empID = 1; //Sets the global variable to = 1
        //This is the same as this.empID = 1;
    }

    public void setEmpID(int newID) {
        empID = newID; //Sets the global variable to = newID
        //This is the same as this.empID = newID;
    }

    public int getEmpID() {
        return empID; //Gets the value of the global variable
                      //empID. Example use below
    }
}
```

**Example2.java**

```
public class Example2 {
    public Example2() {
        Example ex = new Example(1); //Create and initate an Example class
        System.out.println(ex.getEmpID()); //Prints out Example.empID, aka 1
        ex.setEmpID(2);
        System.out.println(ex.getEmpID()); //Prints out Example.empID, aka 2
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example2(); //Creates and initates an Example2 class
    }
}
```

And as for variable types this short tutorial goes through them. [Tutorial](https://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Variables_and_Types)

Comment: So global variables are what are in the (in this program's case) main method? Which I defined as employee employeeTwo =  new employee(100, John, Doe, 3000.01) I know that the first employee is telling to call the "employee" class and the second is telling the main method to create a object from that class named employeeOne and it will be a new employee with the (attributes) are the attributes in parenthesis the global variables? Thank you guys for the wicked fast response!! You guys rock!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your first questions. Global variables can be seen by an entire class, whereas local variables can only be seen by a single method or constructor.

Comment: @chadjensen As for your second part. `Employee employeeTwo` creates a variable. and `employeeTwo = new Employee(100, John, Doe, 3000.01);` initiates the variable so that it can be used. For example in my code example if you ran `Example ex;` and then `System.out.println(ex.getEmpID());` you would get an error

Comment: @chadjensen Does this help clear everything up?

Comment: Dan, your examples are amazing. thank you for taking the time to explain to me. It helped out so much.

Comment: @chadjensen No problem. Would you mind clicking the tick next to my answer if you think it is sufficiently correct?

Comment: On your example why would you print out empID from your Example2 class before you initiate your main method, which creates your Example2 class.

Comment: Or are you just doing like I did, except instead of using two screens to keep them separate(easier to visualize them as being different for a noob) you put them on the same screen?

Comment: I don't. When the main method initiates the `Example2` class it runs the code inside the constructor and I have two examples to show how methods from `Example` can be used in `Example2`. Other than that I'm not entirely sure what you mean